# Pointers dereferencing differences between [] and *

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have come across an opinion that in case we have a pointer to a pointer, we can dereference it via `[][]` in case the allocated memory is adjacent. In case its not, only dereferencing via pointers arithmetic can be used. But I cannot quite reproduce that situation, i.e. here is an example code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ITEMS_NO    3
#define LETTERS_NO  4

int main(void)
{
    char* theArray[ITEMS_NO];
    char* dummyArr[ITEMS_NO];

    for (int i = 0; i < ITEMS_NO; ++i)
    {
        theArray[i] = malloc(LETTERS_NO);
        dummyArr[i] = malloc(LETTERS_NO); // make sure mem is not adjecent

        for (int k = 0; k < LETTERS_NO - 1; ++k)
        {
            theArray[i][k] = '0' + i;
            dummyArr[i][k] = 'z';
        }

        theArray[i][LETTERS_NO - 1] = 0;
        dummyArr[i][LETTERS_NO - 1] = 0;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < ITEMS_NO; ++i)
    {
        printf("item by square bracket %i = %c \n", i, theArray[i][1]);
        printf("item by ptr %i = %c \n", i, *((*(theArray + i)) + 1));
        free(theArray[i]);
        free(dummyArr[i]);
    }
}
```

In this example i allocate the `dummyArr` in order to make sure that the allocated memory for the `theArray` is not adjacentnext to each other. Both `printf` calls give the same results. Am I not getting something here or do both dereferencing methods work exactly the same way?

Comment: The C language itself defines that `p[i]` and `*(p + i)` are *exactly* identical and interchangeable with each other; whatever alignment concerns there are work the same way either way.

Comment: * and [] is the same depending on the type of pointer it is. For instance if the pointer is of type `int` then `pointer[1]` is `sizeof(int)` passed the first index. Likewise `*(pointer+1)` is also `sizeof(int)` passed the first index. And I'm not exactly sure how you're checking the memory isn't alligned. If you want to target a specific byte after index 0 you can cast it to char then add your offset.

Comment: When you say "aligned" do you really mean ["adjacent"](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/adjacent)?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude indeed. Fixed, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two methods are exactly equivalent.  Section 6.5.2.1p2 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) regarding array subscripting states:

> A postfix expression followed by an expression in square brackets `[]`
>   is a subscripted designation of an element of an array object. The
>   definition of the subscript operator `[]` is that `E1[E2]` is identical to
>   `(*((E1)+(E2)))`. Because of the conversion rules that apply to the
>   binary `+` operator, if `E1` is an array object (equivalently, a pointer
>   to the initial element of an array object) and `E2` is an integer,
>   `E1[E2]` designates the `E2`-th element of `E1` (counting from zero).

The fact that you have a pointer-to-pointer, where each pointer points to a distinct array, as opposed to a true 2D array doesn't change this.